# System.import usage cause multiple errors in my console

Tags: typescript, angular

I use `System` in my component.

```
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor() {
        System.import('app/login/login.js');
    }
}
```

File loads fine, but TypeScript compiller says

`Error:(10, 9) TS2304: Cannot find name 'System'.`

And my browser console says

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: http://localhost:3000/app/login/login.js detected as register but didn't execute.
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:332:29)
        at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:2111:31)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:331:35)
        at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:227:44)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/login/login.js

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: http://localhost:3000/app/login/login.js detected as register but didn't execute.(…)
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Why are you using `System.import` in TypeScript instead of the ES6 import syntax? What is `login.js`? What file is `LoginComponent` found in?

Comment: @rgvassar login.js is a script to support my page with animation. How do I import my .js file with ES6 syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error since you don't have typings for the SystemJS library.

Most of time we don't use explicitly `System.import` in TypeScript files since we can make it act under the hood. I mean when you use the following, the TypeScript compiler will convert import into something supported by SystemJS:

```
import {...} from 'app/login/login';

export class LoginComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

You can notice that I remove the `js` extension since SystemJS allows to configure the default extension to add when resolving modules:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm new in TypeScript, so I don't clearly understand how can I import `.js` file using `import {...} from 'app/login/login';`. It just says `Cannot find module 'app/login/login'.`

Comment: My goal is to load `.js` dynamically after template loads. System.import handles this task fine, but raises a lot of errors in the console.

Comment: You need to find typings for SystemJS (a `.d.ts` ) file describing the contract of the library...

Answer (score 0):

> How do I import my .js file with ES6 syntax

Two step:

- declare the JS file in `vendor.d.ts`

  declare module 'app/login/login' {
     var foo:any;
     export = foo;
  }
- use it in your TypeScript

  import * as login from 'app/login/login';

Now just compile your code with '--module system'